# Query using eloquent whereMonth where date is string

Tags: laravel, postgresql, casting, eloquent

In one of the tables a column with type of `varchar` contains a date with the following format `day-month-year`. I would like to run a query using eloquent on that table with `whereYear` and `whereMonth`, but I get an error since the column `booking_date` is not of type Date.

The query I am trying to run is

```
MyTable::whereYear('booking_date', '=', $year)
        ->whereMonth('booking_date', '=', $month)
        ->get();
```

And getting the following error

```
"SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist\nLINE 1: ...\" = $1 and \"said_table\".\"deleted_at\" is null) and extract(ye...\n                                                             ^\nHINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is there a way to cast the string value to a date before querying it, maybe with using raw expressions? If yes, any hints would be great.

Comment: where('booking_date', 'LIKE', '%'.$someDate.'%') could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this field is going to be a date on the particular model all the time (and with a name like 'booking_date', it might well be), it is even easier than having to deal with it on every query.  You can cast it within the dates field on the model itself:

```
protected $dates = [
    'booking_date',
];
```

By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, and the above will do the same for `booking_date`.  No further casting required. From [Laravel docs on date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

You may easily achieve that thanks to Carbon library which is included within Laravel:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

```
$targetDate = Carbon::now()->year($year)->month($month);
MyTable::whereYear('booking_date', '=', $targetDate)
        ->whereMonth('booking_date', '=', $targetDate)
        ->get();
```